# How to correctly specify eclipse-plugins in category.xml of tycho eclipse-repository?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-pde, tycho, p2

I want to create a p2 repository of some eclipse-plugins during a tycho build.

My `category.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
    <feature url="plugins/<artifact-id>-1.0.0.jar"
        id="<artifact-id>" version="1.0.0.qualifier">
        <category name="cat" />
    </feature>
    <category-def name="cat" label="example category" />
</site>
```

where `<artifact-id>` is the maven artifact id of the eclipse-plugin that shall be included in the p2 repo.

When executing the maven build I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found
because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency
from  <repository-module-artifact-id> 1.0.0.qualifier to
<artifact-id>.feature.group[1.0.0,1.0.1).", "No
solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
```

I have included the eclipse-plugin in the dependencies of the repository-module.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as of now you can only reference features in category.xml.

recently there was a patch that will allow referencing individual bundles in a future version of tycho, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=381377

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the bug. I created a feature that contains my plugin. This sounds a bit over engineered for my single plugin, but makes absolutely sense for larger projects.