# Tycho build fails with "No content specified for p2 repository" although there is a category.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, p2

The Eclipse plug-in [Markdown-Editor](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/Eclipse-Markdown-Editor-Plugin) doesn't build with Maven/Tycho. The build fails with the message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:0.18.1:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository)
 on project markdown.editor.site: No content specified for p2 repository -> [Help 1]
```

The similar configuration [StartExplorer plugin](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/startexplorer) works fine:

category.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/markdown.editor.feature_1.0.0.jar" id="markdown.editor.feature" version="1.0.0">
      <category name="markdowneditor"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="markdowneditor" label="Markdown Editor">
      <description>
         Extend the text editor to provide good Markdown support.
      </description>
   </category-def>
</site>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.winterwell.markdown</groupId>
        <artifactId>markdown.editor.parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>markdown.editor.site</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

    <name>Markdown Editor (site)</name>
    <description>Markdown Editor (site)</description>

</project>
```

Related to [tycho-p2-repository-plugin fails with "No content specified for p2 repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124702/tycho-p2-repository-plugin-fails-with-no-content-specified-for-p2-repository)
and [How to correctly specify eclipse-plugins in category.xml of tycho eclipse-repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381676/how-to-correctly-specify-eclipse-plugins-in-category-xml-of-tycho-eclipse-reposi)

Comment: The error message from the log would have been helpful.

Comment: It was `No content specified for p2 repository ->` The problem is solved.

Comment: I'm just trying to allow others to also benefit from your learnings.

Answer (score 3):

If version is defined with ``` -SNAPSHOT``, then in ```category.xml`version should have`.qualifier`

`<feature url="features/markdown.editor.feature_1.0.0.jar" id="markdown.editor.feature" version="1.0.0.qualifier">`